# Google Tag Manager Custom Event not firing

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm fairly new to Google Tag Manager and am trying to set up my first custom event.

In my html I have, in the very top of my head:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  dataLayer.push({"event": "testEvent"});
</script>
```

And in Google Tag Manager, I've created a trigger that uses my "testEvent":

[image]

Additionally, I've created a tag that uses this custom event:

[image]

Lastly, when I debug I see that both my custom event and tag show up:

[image]

However, when I click on the DOM element that is supposed to trigger that custom event, nothing happens.

I have tried swapping out my custom event trigger for just the built-in click trigger and that works fine, so that tells me that I have my tag itself set up correctly.

Am I missing a step? Is there something more I need to do to make a custom event work? Like I said, I know I could use a regular click trigger in this test case, but in my actual project, I cannot just use the regular click trigger.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

it is a configuration issue. If I understand correctly, you're trying to trigger an event tag when someone clicks on an element with a specific css class.

To achieve this, you will need to:

1. Go to the "Variables" screen in GTM. On the top portion of the screen, there is the "Built-in Variables" section. Click on the "CONFIGURE" button, a side menu should pop up. Look for the "Click Classes" under the "Clicks" section. Check the checkbox beside "Click Classes", close this menu, should show now see the "Click Classes" variable name under "Built-in Variables".
2. Go to the "Triggers" screen in GTM. Create a new trigger of the type "All Elements" under the "Click" section. When the configuration for this trigger comes up, select "Some Clicks" under "This trigger fires on". You should see 3 input fields come up for the condition of this trigger. In the first select box, you should see "Click Classes" as one of the available selections, pick that. In the next box, select the appropriate comparison type, we will choose "equals" in this case. In the last input box, put in "search__input" or the name of the css class you want to trigger on.
3. Go back to the "Tags" screen in GTM. Add this trigger to the tag you want and voila!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. But I do already have my variables configured to ensure I have the types I need available. Like I said, if instead of using a custom event, I just the built-in GTM click event, everything works fine. My question is why my custom event -- which does successfully fire -- doesn't cause the tag that is set up to listen to that custom event fire? Again, that same exact tag fires correctly as expected if I change my trigger to be a built in GTM click event, rather than my custom event. Here's a scrrenshot of my preview screen: https://ibb.co/eGBFZ9

Comment: Hi, you shouldn't include "#" and "." for class names, just type in the name of the css class. This way of triggering is very inefficient, but I understand this might be an assignment requirement?

Comment: It's not an assignment. I know this trigger is inefficent for this purpose, but my stackoverflow question is just a reduced test case of the actual problem I'm trying to solve (which requires a custom event). I did try removing the #, but unfortunately it didn't help. The problem isn't that the trigger won't fire (it does - at least that's what I assume it showing up in the preview means); it's just that the tag the depends on the trigger isn't firing.

Comment: Okay, so if you’ve changed your code to push a m event on click of the button, you can just change the trigger to fire an all custom events.

Comment: Hi @XTOTHEL. Can you please answer this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281356/gtm-tag-not-fired

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the element clicks using JQuery or any other language, as well as change the trigger to fire on "All Custom Events"

for example say I have a chat button

```
<script>
  var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
   $('.chatBtn').click(function (e) {
    dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'chat-click'
    });
  });
</script>
```

The event should be on that particular element click .

Looking at your custom event it is not attached to any element click

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I tried your suggestion, but am still having the same core problem. In other words, when I tried your suggestion and then and use GTM preview, I see on initial page load (as expected) my custom event doesn't show up under the summary. However, when I click the button, the custom event does show up under the summary. So that's a good sign that something is going right. However, that trigger firing still isn't causing my tag (which uses that trigger) to fire. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Can you click on the tag in preview mode and share the screen shot

Comment: hmmm I don't seem to be able to edit my question, so I can't add a screenshot that way. Can you see the screenshot I uploaded here? https://ibb.co/eGBFZ9

Comment: looking at the screen shot your click element is wrong , if you correct your trigger ,it will work

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, but I don't think the click element is wrong, since when I click on it the trigger does fire. (or, at least, when I click on it the event suddenly shows up in my GTM Preview summary). The problem is that the tag that is supposed to fire when the trigger goes off doesn't fire.

Comment: only way I can help you now is If I can take a look at exactly whats happening on your screen . However, you can take a look at these links if youc an find any help https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/matches-css-selector-operator-in-gtm-triggers/ , https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/10-useful-css-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

If your custom event is pushed only for "search_input" clicks, then you can the modify your trigger to "All Custom Events"

else as @GTMGuy said you need to push the event on "search_input" click event.During event trigger in GTM preview, click on the event and check the value of Variables - "Click element" whether it matches your trigger condition.